# Golang enforce type for yaml.marshal

Tags: go, types, yaml

I'm running into this case where I have to marshal a map[string]interface{} and print it out. What happens is that when I print it out, the yaml lib (gopkg.in/yaml.v2) converts the ints into strings and surrounds them by quotes while the strings are printed as strings without quotes. Example:

```
prop1: "1"
prop2: test
prop3: test2
```

I need other systems to read these values but could not find a way on enforcing the numeric types when I do yaml.Marshal().

My code for the above output looks something like this:

```
// receive output from somewhere else
pad := "%-16s%s"
raw, err := yaml.Marshal(output)
sArr := strings.Split(raw, "\n")
for _, s := range sArr {
    fmt.Fprintln(c.StdOut, fmt.Sprintf(pad, s, ""))
}
```

Any suggestions how to overcome this?

Thanks in advance! 
JC

Comment: I bet `yaml.Marshal` can't figure out the correct type because of `interface{}` type in your map and throw out everything as `strings`. I had a similar problem when trying to unmarshal data from a JSON with an array of `interface{}`. Can't you marshal it to a `struct`?

Comment: The map interface is not always going to have the same structure so a struct is not an option for this case.